# How to combine two Internet connection into one switch with VLAN

Tags: switch, vlan, hp-procurve

We currently have two different internet providers coming into our office (one is a backup), and each is going into separate switches. From the two different switches they are going up into both of our SonicWall NAS 4600 firewalls. I want to be able to eliminate the two small switches & setup one bigger switch with VLANs to do the job that the two smaller ones were doing. Attached is what it currently looks like, one internet provider is plugged into the Linksys switch & then out of there to the Primary & Secondary Firewall. The second internet provider into TrendNet, & out of there to the Primary & Secondary Firewalls. The firewalls routes everything for us, & does the DHCP. Any suggestions on how this can work?  [image]

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the switch? What kind is it?

Comment: Why not simply plug the ISP directly into the firewall(s)? Why do you want to insert a single point of failure, a single switch, in the topology?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston As it seems, there's just a single handover port for each ISP and they'd want to connect both to each firewall.

Comment: @Zac67 so in that case I would argue that they are adding unnecessary complexity to the design/architecture. Statistically speaking, and assuming the firewalls operate independently vs as a single node, the idea that both a firewall and its connected ISP would fail concurrently is unrealistic. Keep it simple for maximum uptime. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston If the ISP router fails then it's irrelevant whether their backbone is still working. Essentially, there are two WAN connections, each with a single handover port, and the OP wants to create a redundant uplink using redundant firewalls.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston this was setup before I came here, so I am trying to clean things up. Both firewalls have exactly the same info on them through the hear beat cable. That way if the primary firewall goes down the secondary firewall kicks in. So from the ISP fiber converter we go into the each switch, & from each switch their is a connection that goes directly into each firewall for a fell over (is what I was told).

Comment: In that case, the only reason I can see to put a switch or switches between the ISP handoff device(s) and your firewall(s) is to enable you to have some 'outside' switchports which would be getting public IP addresses from your ISP(s). If you don't require that, simply plug the ISP directly into the WAN port on your firewall(s).

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I just talked with someone that used to work here, & the reason for the switches is redundancy. So, from ISP1 to switch & then a connection from switch to Firewall 1 & one to Firewall 2. The same thing with ISP2, & that way if ISP1 goes down it doesn't take down Firewall 1. Hopefully that makes since to why we have the setup this way.

Comment: But you have another Internet link thru ISP2, in other words you already have redundancy. With each firewall dual homed you have double redundancy which may seem smart but it actually adds unnecessary complexity which leads to greater downtime.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Comment: @Zac67 sorry did not know that, but got it taken care of Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a VLAN for each ISP on the bigger switch.

On the ISP-facing switch ports, make sure you permit only that single, untagged VLAN, disable or configure appropriately RSTP/MSTP (BPDU filter, TCN guard), disable LLDP, CDP, etc. Do not configure any IP address.

Towards each firewall you can either use two dedicated access ports or (more elegantly) a single VLAN trunk. You could even run your internal VLAN on the same trunks but I prefer to use an extra link there.

For example, it could look like this:

- VLAN 4001 untagged on port 47 (ISP1)
- VLAN 4002 untagged on port 48 (ISP2)
- VLAN 4001 and 4002 tagged on port 45 (primary firewall)
- VLAN 4001 and 4002 tagged on port 46 (secondary firewall)

On the firewalls, you'd configure two *subinterfaces* (one each for VLANs 4001 and 4002) on the single uplink port, one for each ISP.

For a HPE/Aruba 2530 series switch (from comment) the VLAN/interface would look like something along

```
vlan 4001 name ISP1
vlan 4001 untagged 47
vlan 4001 tagged 45,46
vlan 4002 name ISP2
vlan 4002 untagged 48
vlan 4003 tagged 45,46
spanning-tree 47-48 bpdu-filter tcn-guard root-guard admin-edge-port
```

- `bpdu-filter` disables (rapid/multiple) spanning tree for that port
- `tcn-guard` ignores topology change notification on that port [*]
- `root-guard` prevents any connect switch to become STP root bridge [*]
- `admin-edge-port` skips the initial *blocking* state of a port on link up [*]
- the last three [*] items are gratuitous with `bpdu-filter` but don't hurt, just in case

If you're facing connectivity problems, run the usual checklist:

- do host MACs show up on the intended VLAN?
- can the hosts ping or at least ARP their default gateway?
- can the gateway ping/traceroute the destination?
- does the gateway permit the host packets onto the destination subnet?
- ... and back from the destination to the host?

Comment: I am going to be using HP 2530-24G (J9776A) Switch for this.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Comment: Hi Zac67, Since I am new to doing this, I have a question about the tagged ports. Since we are tagging both ISP1 & 2 on ports 45 & 46 will that cause in conflict? Is there anyway to make the remaining ports work, so we can plug items into it & get out on the network (we would probably have to uplink from another switch into one of the open ports)?

Comment: Using VLAN tags is all about connecting multiple VLANs on a single interface, called a *trunk port* in Cisco land. You can run as many VLANs across a trunk as you want and your switches support - just make sure you configure both sides in the same way. You can connect any device to a VLAN by assigning that VLAN as untagged to the device's port. If that device support VLANs you can use a trunk port with multiple tagged VLANs.

Comment: Hi Zac67, Since Linksys switch as two ports out (one going to each firewall) & the TrendNet has the same thing, wouldn't we need a total of 4 tagged ports?

Comment: A fourth ports for what? As far as I understand your question, you'd like to connect each ISP handover port (untagged) to your two firewalls (tagged). Alternatively, you could use three untagged ports for each ISP (port-.based VLAN) with the exact same ports on the firewalls as before. The tagging just combines both ISP VLANs into a single trunk port between switch and each firewall.

Comment: For redundancy I will need two ports for ISP1 & two separate ports for ISP2. So, what I thought about doing is VLAN 4001 on Port 23 (since this is a 24 Port switch) untagged, & then tagging 19 & 21 for VLAN 4001. Then for ISP2, VLAN 4002 on Port 24 untagged & tagging 20 & 22. I will try to get a diagram to you on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Again, *tagging* VLANs allows for trunking multiple VLANs across a single, physical port/link. If you tag the VLANs, you only require a single link between switch and firewall, carrying *both* ISP VLANs (still separated, of course). If you want dedicated physical ports for that (= port-based VLANs, resembling the initial setup w/o the separate switches), you'd configure untagged switch ports (one for each VLAN and firewall, 4 total + 2 for ISPs) and connect those exactly like the current separate switches. No change on the firewalls.

Comment: I have the 24 port setup just like you explained, but I am not getting any internet our. VLAN 4001 (ISP 1) Untagged 23, & tagged 19 & 21. VLAN 4002 (ISP 2) Untagged 24, & tagged on 20 & 22. If I plug into port 23 I should be getting internet our of 19 & 21, but I am not. The same goes with the second VLAN, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Chad I've added a common checklist to verify connectivity in incrementing steps. "getting Internet" isn't a good test.